# How to get mySQL table data into java script variable into Node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, global-variables, arrow-functions

I am able to console the result using mysql query (using arrow function result parameter) but can't pass that data to global variable, or return as a fuction, or push into any list.

```
const {createPool} = require('mysql');

const pool = createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root123',
    database: 'accounts_db',
    connectionLimit: 10
})

const sql = 'SELECT * FROM `accounts`';

var dataList = [];

pool.query(sql, (err, result, fields) => {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else {
        // console.log(result); //able to see this data

        dataList.push(result);

    }    
})

console.log(dataList); // I am getting the [] as no data get pused to list.
```

I also used JSON Stringfy to unpack the rawDataPacket but still unable to send that data to any veriable to use that globally.

const {createPool} = require('mysql');

```
const pool = createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root123',
    database: 'accounts_db',
    connectionLimit: 10
})

const sql = 'SELECT * FROM `accounts`';

var dataList = [];
var simpleData = null;
pool.query(sql, (err, result, fields) => {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else {
        // console.log(result);
        dataList.push(result);
        simpleData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
        console.log(simpleData); // console this statement

    }    
})

console.log(simpleData); // result null
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to how promises work with JavaScript's asynchronous code flow. And unfortunately the `mysql` package has no way of awaiting the query result, however you can workaround this by awaiting a manual promise.

```js
var dataList = await new Promise((resolve) => {
  pool.query(sql, (err, result, fields) => {
      if (err)
          console.log(err);
      else {
          resolve(result);
      }    
  })
});
```